# Autobahn Websocket: listen to local port and transfer messages to clients connected to a public port

Tags: python, websocket, autobahn

I'am new to Autobahn and Websockets. 
I'm trying to build the following setup:

- processing service (Java based blackbox):

  - waits for data from twitter's streaming api
  - if new messages are recieved, a message is send to the mainservice (ws://localhost:9999)
    {id, latitude, longitude}
  - does some magic processing with the data (which can take a few minutes)
- mainservice listening on ws://localhost:9999 for incomming messages from processing service

  - if message comes in (from processing service), they are broadcasted to the clients connected on ws://:9000
- javascript clients connected to mainservice on ws://:9000 displaying the messages on a map

Is it possible to write the mainservice with Autobahn listening on one port and delivering messages over another port? (From a performance view it might be better to combine the processing and the mainservice...but that shouldn't be the point here.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can run multiple services on different ports or you can run multiple services on 1 port. For the latter, see [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/websocket/multiproto). For the former, just create multiple factories and call `listenWs` multiple times.